# How to share file record audio to other apps?

Tags: java, android

I am doing record audio and record audio successful, but when I want share file record audio that can not share file. But when I want to share the recording file I just finished recording, it can't be shared. The system says that can't share this file format.
Below is the code I made:

```
    String filePath;
    String audioFile;
    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    public void startRecordAudio(){
        File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "record_audio");
        if (!myDirectory.exists()) {
            myDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mmddyyyyhhmmss");
        String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        audioFile = getResources().getString(R.string.record_audio) + " "+ date;
        filePath = myDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + audioFile+".m4a";

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        try {
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(filePath);
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
            mediaRecorder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void saveRecordAudio(){
        mediaRecorder.pause();
        if (mediaRecorder != null) {
            try {
                //stop mediaRecorder
                mediaRecorder.stop();
                mediaRecorder.reset();
            }catch (IllegalStateException  e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, filePath);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "Record one");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)+" Record Audio");

        getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    }
    
    public void shareFileRecordAudio(){
        String sharePath = filePath;
        Log.d("ldldlld",sharePath);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("audio/*m4a");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
    }
    
    buttonSaveRecordAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            saveRecordAudio();
        }
    });
    
     buttonStartRecordAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startRecordAudio();
        }
    });
    
    buttonShareFileRecordAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            shareFileRecordAudio();
        }
    });
```

How to I can share the recording file just finished recording to other apps?
Thank you!

Comment: Try replacing `share.setType("audio/*m4a");` with `share.setType("audio/*");`

Comment: I tried. But the system still says that Can't Share This File Format

Comment: Okay, if you can include the `error` message in the question, others also can see and help.

Comment: No error in logcat, only the system still says that Can't Share This File Format